# How can I make youtube video responsive along with background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have responsive background and I want to have a YouTube video over that background(not in full width).

Here I have tried doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EGgaN/#run

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-image">
            <img src="http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg">
             <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/R8wHnwfHscw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-image {
position: relative;
}  
.bg-image img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-image iframe {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You want the iframe to always be 560 width?  or 100%?

Comment: max 560 and then reduce it for mobile devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle forked from your fiddle that has the image as the background, as well as a responsive youtube video centered. Making the image have `position:absolute` takes it out of the normal flow and allows the embedded video to stay on top.

The trick for the responsive video code is to wrap the embedded video in a container with a max width, and then also adding in padding to keep the proper aspect ratio for the video. You then ensure that the `iframe`, `object`, and `embded` elements all fit at 100% of that container's width while also not getting any taller than the native size:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    max-height: 320px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QRkL9/

More about the above code - http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

Answer (score 0):

braican is correct, but the 56.25% on the video container will leave lots of padding after your video. Just wrap everything inside another div with a max-height of 320px and overflow:hidden to hide the extra padding;