# How to make a YouTube embedded video and background image responsive together if they are different sizes?

Tags: html, css, youtube, responsive-design, embed

I have implemented a tweaked solution that I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456308/how-can-i-make-youtube-video-responsive-along-with-background-image)

on a dev site for a client I have [here](http://judah.ucdevwork.com/)

The problem I'm now facing is that when the browser is resized, they don't resize together and become misaligned. Someone suggested possibly using two separate images to the left and right of the video, but I've tried several things that didn't work...

The images for that possible solution are:

[image: scroll left]

and

[image: scroll right]

Would someone be willing to give me a hand with a solution that works? The idea is that the video is the actual "scroll" in the middle, and resizes together with the scroll edges (left and right), but I just can't seem to get it to work. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Some thoughts: Yon can use the elastic video trick: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos. The images you can insert as background images with :after and :before pseudo elements on the container. And with `background-size: contain;` they will be scaled. May be it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The answer provided by Vinícius worked for me - I appreciate the time you took to comment, though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really dude you should think a bit more about your layout, anyway to do what you want here is the code:

CSS

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 42%;
    padding-top: 15%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 12.5%;
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning. :) Thank you so so so much, Vinícius!! That code worked perfectly!! :D

Comment: Muito muito muito obrigada! ;)